# Browser detection using user agent in fixture hooks

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I have a few tests that only need to be run when in a mobile browser. Currently I have a client function to check the user agent.

```
const checkMobile = ClientFunction(() => /iPhone|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
```

Which I then access inside my tests:

```
test("Check if mobile", async t => { 
  const isMobile = await checkMobile();
  if (isMobile) {
    await t
    // do the tests
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to use this in a fixture? Like a fixture which will only run if `checkMobile` is `true`? So I don't need to repeat this check in every test manually. I'm sure there's a smarter way to go about it than what I have right now. I tried doing the check in the fixture's `beforeEach` hook but it didn't work out for me to then try to share the outcome of that in a variable to pass down to the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To share a variable from the fixture hook for testing, you can use `fixture context` https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests.html#share-variables-between-test-hooks-and-test-code

In addition, you can reorganize your test in the following manner:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';


fixture `test`.page('http://example.com').beforeEach(async t => {
    const isMobile = await checkMobile();

    t.ctx.isMobile = isMobile;
})

const checkMobile = ClientFunction(() => /iPhone|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent))

function testAndCheck (testName, testFn) {
    const foo = async t => {
        if (t.ctx.isMobile)
            await testFn(t)
        else
            throw new Error('not mobile');
    }

    test(testName, foo);
}

testAndCheck('test1', async t => {
    await t.click('h1');
    await t.click('div');
    await t.click('h1');
})
```

Here I define the `testAndCheck` function that extends the `test` function with an additional check for mobile devices.

In addition, you can refer to this comment https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1626#issuecomment-417424558 to see which other ways exist to overcome the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much Alex! Before I approve your answer I'd like to clarify if it's possible to check if it's mobile first before running the entire fixture? I don't really want to throw an error, just want to skip the whole fixture (which I'm putting all my mobile tests in, so would make sense on desktop to skip it completely)

Comment: It's not required to throw an error. You can just avoid using the `else` branch. 
If suggested solutions don't suit your needs, you can reorganize your test approach. For example, run the testcafe command twice for desktop and mobile devices:
`testcafe chrome,firefox desktop-tests.js`
`testcafe remote mobile.js`
Or, you can use the new testcafe filtering feature http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--fixture-meta-keyvaluekey2value2
`testcafe chrome my-tests --fixture-meta device=mobile,env=production`

Comment: Is it possible to skip tests within the `before` hooks of the fixture?

Comment: @sammiepls, For now, you can achieve the desired behavior only by using the workaround which I suggested in my answer. You can replace the `isMobile` condition with yours. However, I think that it would be nice to have this feature, so probably we'll implement it in the future.