# Async/await t test codes are not working in in beforeEach of TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I tried to use `beforeEach` in TestCafe, a function with some test codes inside of it seems not working properly.
I am using `doLogin` in all different fixtures and tests.

#### Not working

```js
const doLogin = async (t) => {
  const login = new Login();

  await t
    .maximizeWindow()
    .typeText(login.emailInput, accounts.EMAIL_SUCCESS, { replace: true, paste: true })
    .expect(login.emailInput.value).eql(accounts.EMAIL_SUCCESS, 'check an email')
    .typeText(login.passwordInput, accounts.PASSWORD, { paste: true })
    .click(login.loginButton);
};

fixture`App > ${menuName}`
  .page`${HOST}`
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    // This function is called
    // but tests inside the function were not run
    doLogin(t)
  });
```

#### Working Case with a fixture

```js
fixture`App > ${menuName}`
  .page`${HOST}`
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    const login = new Login();

    // But this case is working.
    await t
      .maximizeWindow()
      .typeText(login.emailInput, accounts.EMAIL_SUCCESS, { replace: true, paste: true })
      .expect(login.emailInput.value).eql(accounts.EMAIL_SUCCESS, 'check an email')
      .typeText(login.passwordInput, accounts.PASSWORD, { paste: true })
      .click(login.loginButton);
  });
```

#### Working Case with calling from a test

```js
test(`show all ${menuName} menu's components`, async (t) => {
  // When I added a function directly into a test function then it worked.
  doLogin(t);
  // some codes
```

Could anyone tell me the problem in this code?

In the [official document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219157/browser-detection-using-user-agent-in-fixture-hooks/53259387#53259387), it said `At the moment test hooks run, the tested webpage is already loaded, so that you can use test actions and other test run API inside test hooks.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alex Skorkin, thank you for fixing grammar. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you missed the `await` keyword before the `doLogin()` call:

```
fixture`App > ${menuName}`
  .page`${HOST}`
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    // Don't forget about await
    await doLogin(t)
  });
```

Due to the implementation details it's possible to call an `async` function without `await` in some cases, but it's better to not rely on this and always use `await` with `async` functions.

If you add the `async` keyword and it don't fix the test, feel free to create [a bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe repository and provide a complete example that can be run to reproduce the problem.